# Using NLP output for subsequent model?

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, spacy

I use SpaCy to output a vectorized array of my text field. I'm having issues plugging this output into my random forest and could use some guidance. I label encoded other fields so my pandas dataframe looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

d = {'le1': [0,1,2,1], 'le2': [3,0,2,1], 'spacy_output':[[0.12,0.14,3.5],[1.21,0.84,1.92],[0.34,0.85,2.43],[0.09,0.18,2.21]], 'response':[0,1,1,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then I try to plug this into my model:

```
X = np.array(df.drop(response, axis=1))
y = df[response].values.ravel()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 23)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_split=4, n_estimators=100, criterion='entropy')
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Confused on how to pass this dataframe to my model. I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You can't pass in an array as a single input to the random forest, you therefore have to split the array into several columns such that each number in the array is a separate feature for the model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wanted to make sure that splitting the array as mentioned wouldn't result in any loss of information, but from your answer it doesn't seem like it would